# Why Qt Quick Extension Plugin different on Qt6 and Qt5

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qt6

I create two Qt Quick Extension Plugins.

in Qt6

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls

Button {
    width: 50
    height: 50
    text: "my button"
}
```

in Qt5

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

Button {
    width: 200
    height: 200
    text: "my button"
}
```

In plugin.cpp I add:

```cpp
qmlRegisterType(QUrl("qrc:/MyButton.qml"),uri, 1, 0, "MyButton");
```

Then I generate the dll and the plugins.qmltypes file with Qt5.15.2 MSVC 2019 and Qt 6.4 MSVC 2019.

If I use the dll of Qt 5, it will display:
[image]

But when I use the dll of Qt6, it only display:
[image]

Why Qt6 dll can not display the default property, am I missing something, or does Qt6 need to configure other properties?

Comment: Why do you register a QML component with `qmlRegisterType()` in the first place? Can't you just use `qmldir` instead?

Comment: @GooRoo Hi GooRoo, I'm sorry that I can't understand what you mean. I registered the types to generate qmltypes information, and actually I use the qmldir, but it does not display the default property, any suggestions?

Comment: I get all properties displayed for the MyButton item (I'm using QT 6.4.3). Have you tried to reset you QML code model?

Comment: @JürgenLutz Yes, I have tried to reset the code model mode but it does not work.